# Create variable group headings and indent labels in table

Tags: stata

I am generating a table of means in Stata and trying to export it as a `TeX` file after formatting it in a certain way. I am using the *community-contributed* `estout` family of commands to do so, and I am very close to get the result I want.

However, I cannot figure out how to insert a few additional rows and labels in the generated output.

I have tried the code below:

```
eststo  clear
eststo, title("Mean"): estpost sum Male Female Race1 Race2 Age1-Age6 Education1-Education6
esttab using "${outdir}\Demographic.tex", label mtitles title(Demographic Information) ///
main(mean) b(2) nostar nogaps nonote replace
```

The above code generates the following table:

[image: This code generates table like this.]

What I want is to present different variables in a group. For example `Male` and `Female` should be indented under the heading "Gender" and similarly other variables to be indented under the headings of "Race", "Age" and "Education".

Of course. I can manually add those rows in the `TeX` code and indent these variables, but I want to generate the fully formatted table from Stata.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `estout` command does not directly support this feature but below is a workaround demonstrated with a toy example using artificially-generated data:

```
clear
set obs 246

local vars Male Female Race1 Race2 Age1 Age2 Age3 Age4 Age5 Age6 Education1 /// 
      Education2 Education3 Education4 Education5 Education6

foreach var of local vars {
    generate `var' = runiform()
    label variable `var' "     `var'"
}

eststo clear
eststo, title("Mean"): estpost sum Male Female Race1 Race2 Age1-Age6 Education1-Education6

esttab, label mtitles title(Demographic Information) main(mean) b(2) nostar nogaps nonote ///
refcat(Male "Gender" Race1 "Race" Age1 "Age" Education1 "Education", nolabel)
```

The idea here is to introduce the spacing in each variable's label and then instruct `esttab` to create 'reference categories' before each group.

The above code snippet produces the desired output:

```
Demographic Information
---------------------------------
                              (1)
                             Mean
---------------------------------
Gender                           
     Male                    0.52

     Female                  0.55

Race                             
     Race1                   0.51

     Race2                   0.46

Age                              
     Age1                    0.48

     Age2                    0.47

     Age3                    0.51

     Age4                    0.48

     Age5                    0.50

     Age6                    0.52

Education                        
     Education1              0.51

     Education2              0.52

     Education3              0.50

     Education4              0.48

     Education5              0.48

     Education6              0.50

---------------------------------
Observations                  246
---------------------------------
```

Note that the available space is fixed so you may have to shorten some of your labels. Also, for longer labels you will need to adjust the spacing to bring them in alignment with the rest.

---

**EDIT:**

For `LaTeX` to typeset the spaces correctly, you need to introduce them in each variable's label using the appropriate markup as follows:

```
label variable `var' "\hspace{0.5cm}`var'"
```

Comment: you are awesome!